# Stored procedure for Delete record

Tags: sql-server

I have created 3 stored procedures for inserting, updating and deleting records.

While insert and update record stored procedures are working fine, I can't delete records through the delete stored procedure.

The code in that stored procedure is here:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE usp_DeleteEmployeeRcord
    (@Name NVarchar(50),
     @FName Nvarchar(50),
     @Address NVarchar (50),
     @Email Nvarchar(50),
     @Mobile NVarchar(50),
     @Pincode NVarchar(50))
AS 
BEGIN
    DELETE [dbo].[EmployeeDetails]  
    WHERE Pincode = @Pincode
END
```

Comment: Tell us what error you get or does it simple fail without an error?

Answer (score 2):

You forgot the FROM clause in your statement, it's

```
DELETE FROM dbo.EmployeeDetails WHERE ....
```

Answer (score 2):

Because your `DELETE` statement is not correct. Correct syntax is

```
DELETE FROM <TableName> Where <Condition>
```

So change your query to this and then try

```
DELETE FROM [dbo].[EmployeeDetails] Where Pincode = @Pincode
```

Comment: What would happen to the table if you started this procedure and then cancelled it partway thru the execution? 

Would any rows deleted prior to cancelling stay deleted or would the server roll back then deletions?

Answer (score 0):

You have to make variables optional which you are not passing in the procedure:

Use this modified:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE usp_DeleteEmployeeRcord
(
 @Name NVarchar(50)='',
 @FName Nvarchar(50)='', 
 @Address NVarchar (50)='', 
 @Email Nvarchar(50)='', 
 @Mobile NVarchar(50)='', 
 @Pincode NVArchar(50)
)

AS 
        BEGIN
            DELETE [dbo].[EmployeeDetails]  
            Where Pincode = @Pincode
        END
```

Hope it helps. :)

Comment: your code will give a syntax error. Please post your code only after testing for yourself.

Comment: what is the error you getting, could you please tell?

Comment: You might can get error that object usp_DeleteEmployeeRcord already exists, so you just delete the previous or alter procedure, whatever you like.

Comment: Yes, for MS SQL Server 'FROM' is optional in DELETE Statement. :) try it

Answer (score 0):

Stored Procedure for Delete Record -
Example of Book Details as Follow:

```
    Create procedure[dbo].[DeleteBookDetails_SP] 
         @BookId Int
    As
    Begin   

         Delete from BookDetails Where BookId=@BookId

    End
```

Here "DeleteBookDetails_SP" is Stored Procedure Name , "BookDetails" is Table Name and "BookId" is Column Name in Table.

Comment: The Create statement has to be Create procedure[dbo].[DeleteBookDetails_SP](@BookId Int) and not as Create procedure[dbo].[DeleteBookDetails_SP] @BookId Int

Answer (score 0):

```
Use test
go

CREATE TABLE employee(  
id INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,  
first_name VARCHAR(10),  
last_name VARCHAR(10),  
salary DECIMAL(10,2),  
city VARCHAR(20), 
)  


INSERT INTO employee VALUES (2, 'Monu', 'Rathor',4789,'Agra');  
GO  

INSERT INTO employee VALUES (4, 'Rahul' , 'Saxena', 5567,'London');  
GO  

INSERT INTO employee VALUES (5, 'prabhat', 'kumar', 4467,'Bombay'); 
go  

INSERT INTO employee VALUES (6, 'ramu', 'kksingh', 3456, 'jk');  
go  

select * from employee 


Create procedure MasterInsertUpdateDelete
(
@ID integer,  --//Mandatory parameters
@Firstname varchar(50)=Null,  --//optional parameters//--
@Lastname varchar(50)=Null,
@Salary Decimal(10, 2)=Null,
@City varchar(20)=Null,
@Statementtype nvarchar(200) = '' 
)
as
Begin

    if @Statementtype = 'Insert'
    begin
        insert into employee(id, first_name, last_name, salary, city) values(@ID, @Firstname, @Lastname, @Salary, @City)
    end

    if @Statementtype = 'Select'
    begin
            select *
        from employee
    end
    if @Statementtype = 'Update'
    begin
        update employee set first_name = @Firstname, last_name=@Lastname, salary=@Salary, city=@City
        where id=@ID
    end

    if @Statementtype = 'Delete' 
    begin
    delete from  employee where id=@ID
    end
end

--For insert the records
exec MasterInsertUpdateDelete 7, 'Kallesh', 'Yadav', 30000, 'Bangalore', 'Insert'


--For update the records
exec MasterInsertUpdateDelete 4,'Sneha', 'Kumari', 23000, 'Mumbai', 'Update'

select *
from employee

--For delete the records
exec MasterInsertUpdateDelete  @ID = 2,  @Statementtype = 'Delete' -->We should specify the parameters name while deleting the specific records
```

Hope it helps. :)

Comment: In this stored proc can insert, update,  retrieve and delete the records